# Calling Get function from a html view

Tags: javascript, get

I have javascript code which returns a partial view.

```
var url1="";
 $.get(url1, { 'id': Gid }, function (result) {
 $("#abcd").html(result);   
  });
```

View returning is

```
<div id="goalReport">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

   function LoadReport() {
   }
  </script>
```

i want to call the load report function on success of the get function i wrote.

How can i call the load report function instead  of appending it in a div abcd
i tried like

```
result.LoadReport
```

but it is not working

Comment: On which event you want to call LoadReport?

Comment: as result  of get function i am getting this view. inside that the load report function is included.

Comment: u cannot do that..... wat actually you are doing in LoadReport() function..?? can u post the Loadreport() code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the things you define in javascript are in the same context. It's not like C# or some other languages although you have the scope definition and even you can have namespaces. So you can simply change the code to this:

```
var url1="";

$.get(url1, { 'id': Gid }, function (result) {

     //If the result contains the HTML code you mentioned you should append it to the document
     //and browser will initialize the script tag and everything inside it (So you MUST append the script tag to be initiated). So you can call the 
     //function whenever the script tag is loaded. Because you didn't use the src attribute to 
     // reference a javascript file, I think you can call the function on the next line, after
     // appending the element.

     $(result).appendTo(document.body);    

      LoadReport();

   }
);
```

However there is another way that you can find the script contents by some RegEx or string functions and call the `"eval"` function and initialize it without appending the html code to the document. I myself don't recommend this way because it's a buggy idea and it may cause you some silly exceptions.

Hope it helps
Cheers

Comment: Cheers bro, I am thinking of another way to call this eval($("script", $(result)).text()) but I'm not sure that it's working or not. Hope to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get(url1, { 'id': Gid }, LoadReport);
```

Is this what you want? Sorry, I don't fully understood your question

Comment: no, this get function is returning this loadreport function which is warpped in a an html view. i want to call loadreport function from that view. the result contains the loadreport function. i want to acess the load report function from result can i acess like result.LoadReport???

Comment: I'd suggest you to move js scripts to separate file and then add <script> to page on some action

Comment: $.get(url1, { 'id': Gid }, LoadReport); this code will do the same.